Why is / in my URL slug converted to %2F in ASP.NET Core?
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Razor pages project where I have URLs that include both a culture code and a slug, separated by a slash (/). This structure helps in identifying different language versions of content. For example, a course URL might look like this:
https://localhost:7213/CourseDetails/en/learn-english-in-99-days

In the database, I store these slugs as a single string with the format culture/slug, like:

en/learn-english-in-99-days
prs/learn-farsi-in-30-days

However, when I try to pass this slug in the URL, it often gets URL-encoded to %2F or decoded into a space under certain conditions. This happens even if I pass the slug with a slash (/), and it seems inconsistent.
Example problem

In the database, I have the slug stored as en/learn-english-in-99-days.

When I navigate to the URL in my browser like this:
https://localhost:7213/CourseDetails/en%2Flearn-english-in-99-days

The browser converts %2F to a slash, resulting in this URL:
https://localhost:7213/CourseDetails/en/learn-english-in-99-days


When ASP.NET Core processes the request, the converted URL (with / instead of %2F) doesn't match the slug stored in the database. This causes issues, such as not finding the course and returning a 404 error.


What I've tried

Custom Middleware: I attempted to create middleware to replace %2F with / in the request path, but this still led to issues when the browser would display the decoded path with slashes.

Manual encoding and decoding: I used Uri.UnescapeDataString to decode the ID in the OnGet handler in my Razor page, but it still doesn't resolve the problem fully since the encoding and decoding appear inconsistent.


Question
Why does the slash (/) get converted to %2F or sometimes a space, even when it’s stored as a regular slash in the database? How can I maintain the correct encoding/decoding so that the URL matches the format stored in the database, allowing me to retrieve the correct resource?
Environment

ASP.NET Core Razor pages
Running locally with URLs like https://localhost

Any advice on how to handle URL encoding issues with slashes in ASP.NET Core, or suggestions on structuring my routes to avoid this problem, would be greatly appreciated!

If you need to use a slash (/) in a URL as part of a single segment (e.g. en/learn-english-in-99-days), try replacing it with %2F up front and then processing the request so that ASP.NET Core correctly treats the string as a single path segment.

"However, when I try to pass this slug in the URL, it often gets URL-encoded to %2F or decoded into a space under certain conditions." Are you saying that URLs generated by your applications (such as hyperlinks) have the slash encoded? That seems like a problem that can be solved, but we'd need an example of how you generate said URL for display.

/ and %2F are different things in the URL. Instead of trying to "fix" the incoming URL, address how those URLs are being made in the first place.

I have a Courses page where each course has a slug consisting of the culture and title, like en/learn-english-in-99-days. When clicking on a course, the slug is passed to the CourseDetails page via asp-route-id, like this:
<a asp-page="/CourseDetails" asp-route-id="@course.Slug" class="coursesCard -type-1">


But the slash (/) in the slug gets encoded as %2F, causing issues when retrieving the course from the database.

This version includes the clickable link as well.

Please share a [mcve].

When you pass a URL segment containing special characters like / to an anchor tag helper, it's automatically URL-encoded to ensure safe transmission, hence the / being converted to %2F
An easy solution would be to use a standard anchor element and pass the slug to the href attribute:
<a href="/coursedetails/@course.Slug">
